# How can I re-create an accordion from a filtered list

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion which I populate using a custom list. However I have a button which kicks off a javascript function to filter the list based on values in 3 different drop-downs. This also works but my issue is on how to destroy the accordion already on the page and re-create accordion with the new filtered list. At the moment the new list is appended to the old accordion (which at least proves my filter function is working). I have tried using "$('#accordion').append('destroy')" but the new list continues to be appended to the end of the old list.

Here is how I am generating the accordion currently:

```
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
     var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

listItemInfo += '\nRoom Name: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title')+ ' ' +'Building: ' + oListItem.get_item('Building') + ' ' + 'Floor: ' + oListItem.get_item('Floor') + ' ' + 'Seating: ' + oListItem.get_item('Seating')
+ ' ' +  'Phone Number: ' + oListItem.get_item('Phone_x0020_Number') + ' ' +  'Book Room: ' + oListItem.get_item('Book_x0020_Room')  ;



    var newDiv = "<h3> " +oListItem.get_item('Title').toString() +"  </h3><div> <p> Building :  " +oListItem.get_item('Building').toString()+" </p> </br><p> Floor :" +oListItem.get_item('Floor').toString()+" </p></br><p> Phone Number :" +oListItem.get_item('Phone_x0020_Number').toString()+" </p></br><p> General Size :" +oListItem.get_item('General_x0020_Size').toString()+" </p></br><p> Book Room : <a href =" +oListItem.get_item('Book_x0020_Room').get_url()+">" +oListItem.get_item('Book_x0020_Room').get_description()+"</a> </p></div>";        

$('#accordion').append(newDiv)
    $('#accordion').accordion("refresh"); 



}
```

I also have this div in my html body:

```
<div id="accordion"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help from my boss on this one. Had to use the empty method `$( '#accordion').empty();`to empty out the contents of the accordion div just before my while loop. Also there really is no need for `$('#accordion').accordion("refresh");` in my code.